# Dynamically add columns to query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am looking for a query to summarized data representing manufacturing job operations in one line. For example, a job can have multiple operations and not all jobs have the same operations. Then concatenate the Operation with Hors and estimated hours.

| JobNum | Operation | Hours | Estimate | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fabrication | 5 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | Paint | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Packaging | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Fabrication | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2 | Welding | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | Paint | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | Packaging | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | Fabrication | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Packaging | 0.25 | 0.5 | 1 |

What I am looking for is something like this

| JobNum | Operation | Operation | Operation | Operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fabrication (5/6) | Paint (1/1) | Packaging (0/1) |  |
| 2 | Fabrication (6/6) | Welding (2/4) | Paint (0/2) | Packaging (0/1) |
| 3 | Fabrication (3/2) | Packaging (0.25/0.5) |  |  |

I tried using a Pivot, but I need to define all operations as columns leaving multiple NULL columns in each row.

| JobNum | Fabrication | Welding | Paint | Packaging |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fabrication (5/6) | NULL | Paint (1/1) | Packaging (0/1) |
| 2 | Fabrication (6/6) | Welding (2/4) | Paint (0/2) | Packaging (0/1) |
| 3 | Fabrication (3/2) | NULL | NULL | Packaging (0.25/0.5) |

Comment: Thats pretty much how SQL works... its a data storage and retrieval system, not a display system. Your front end will be able to do that much easier.

Comment: This would require dynamic SQL, and is more than trivial. Your presentation layer, as mentioned, would be a much better choice of tool to create this result set.

Comment: Do you need it as separate columns or would a single column like "Fabrication (5/6), Paint (1/1), Packaging (0/1)" be sufficient? If the latter, maybe you just want to use `string_agg` around a subquery.

Comment: Is there a known set of operations or will it dynamically have to adapt to new operation types (even typos - I feel like there should be an Operations table and this should just have foreign keys)? Is there a deterministic way to dictate that Welding comes before Paint and Paint comes before Packaging? Is it enforced that each JobNum can only have one row per operation?

Comment: You can use the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...) function to assign sequnce numbers to the operations within each job and pivot on that. An alternative to PIVOT that is sometimes easier to manage is *conditional aggregation* of the form `SELECT ..., MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN  Operation END) AS Oparation3`.  (E.g., what @siggemannen just posted.)

Comment: The output does need to be in separate columns. There is a known set of operations. New development, each operation is paired with an operation sequence and the order may not be the same for every job. Same output, but the operations are sorted left to right by the operation sequence.

Comment: Where do we find the "operation sequence" in the sample data you've shown? How do I know that in job 1, fabrication comes before paint, and paint comes before packaging? As a human you know this (not my industry but that makes logical sense to me), but how do we tell SQL Server, because it is not powered by AI? Is there a column you're not sharing? Or you do expect SQL Server to remember what order the rows were inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution, assuming there is a max of 4 types of operations:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT JobNum,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobNum ORDER BY @@SPID),
    [H/E] = CONCAT(Operation,' (',Hours,'/',Estimate,')')
  FROM dbo.whoknows AS w
)
SELECT JobNum, Operation = COALESCE([1], ''), 
               Operation = COALESCE([2], ''), 
               Operation = COALESCE([3], ''),
               Operation = COALESCE([4], '')
FROM src PIVOT 
(MAX([H/E]) FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS p;
```

[Working db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/0j--C4xn).

If you need it to be smart about adapting to any number of operations, you can build a [dynamic `PIVOT`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand):

```
DECLARE @numOps int, 
  @output nvarchar(max), 
  @cols   nvarchar(max),
  @sql    nvarchar(max);

SELECT @numOps = COUNT(DISTINCT Operation) FROM dbo.whoknows;

;WITH OpCount AS
(
  SELECT rn = QUOTENAME(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID))
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(',', @numOps - 1), ',')
)
SELECT @output = STRING_AGG(CONCAT('Operation = COALESCE(', 
   rn, ', '''')'),',
'), @cols = STRING_AGG(rn, ',') FROM OpCount;

SET @sql = CONCAT(N';WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT JobNum,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobNum ORDER BY @@SPID),
    [H/E] = CONCAT(Operation,'' ('',Hours,''/'',Estimate,'')'')
  FROM dbo.whoknows AS w
)
SELECT JobNum, ', @output, ' FROM src PIVOT 
(MAX([H/E]) FOR rn IN (', @cols, ')) AS p;');

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

[Also with a db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/-_esRggB).

Output in both cases:

| JobNum | Operation | Operation | Operation | Operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fabrication (5/6) | Paint (1/1) | Packaging (0/1) |  |
| 2 | Fabrication (6/6) | Welding (2/4) | Paint (0/2) | Packaging (0/1) |
| 3 | Fabrication (3/2) | Packaging (0.25/0.5) |  |  |

And finally, for the late-breaking requirement of SQL Server 2014 (<shudder>):

```
DECLARE @numOps int,           @output nvarchar(max), 
        @sql    nvarchar(max), @cols   nvarchar(max);

SELECT @numOps = COUNT(DISTINCT Operation) FROM dbo.whoknows;

;WITH OpCount AS (
  SELECT r = 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT r+1 FROM OpCount WHERE r < @numOps
), ocols AS 
(
    SELECT c = STUFF((SELECT ',' 
      + CONCAT('Operation = COALESCE(', QUOTENAME(r), ', '''')')
    FROM OpCount ORDER BY r
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
), pcols AS 
(
    SELECT c = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(r))
    FROM OpCount ORDER BY r
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
)
SELECT @output = (SELECT c FROM ocols),
       @cols   = (SELECT c FROM pcols)
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 255);

SET @sql = CONCAT(N';WITH src AS (
  SELECT JobNum,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobNum ORDER BY @@SPID),
    [H/E] = CONCAT(Operation,'' ('',Hours,''/'',Estimate,'')'')
  FROM dbo.whoknows AS w )
SELECT JobNum, ', @output, ' FROM src PIVOT 
(MAX([H/E]) FOR rn IN (', @cols, ')) AS p;');

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

[Working example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/LWJg56qU). That could probably be tidier but old, unsupported versions aren't worth the effort IMHO.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) i didn't know one could use niladic functions here! Even USER works. And i've been wasting time doing (select NULL) all those years

Comment: @siggemannen I use `@@SPID` unless I want to prevent parallelism in which case I use `@@TRANCOUNT`. Picked that up from Paul White and/or Itzik Ben-Gan several years back.

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks for sharing this information, i'll have to read up on it. Btw, i guess this is a bit off topic, but why is there difference between row_number() over(order by (select newid())) and row_number() over(order by newid())? First doesn't randomize while second does. There's no difference when you select the values outside of the row_number

Comment: `(select newid())` -> converted to constant first (at least in _that_ construct, but not as part of the SELECT list). `order by newid()` is evaluated for every row no matter where it is mentioned.

Comment: I like the second example, it does what I need. However, I did not realize that this one would running on our 2014 server and STRING_AGG is not available.

Comment: @mchernecki For future questions please take care to tag with the lowest required version, it will prevent people from wasting time crafting solutions you can't use.

Comment: Apologies, we are running SQL 2019 on everything else but this database, which is scheduled to be upgraded by years end. Your solution does have value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little tip, don't "start" any SQL solution by using pivots, it should only be for style points when you're already done.
There's nothing magical about that operator, it very seldom saves any kind of time, and it has a ton of limitations and awkward syntax.

If you have a fixed amount operation you can use the following pseudo-pivot instead:

```sql
select  jobnum
,   ISNULL(MAX(case when sort = 1 then Operation end), '') operation
,   ISNULL(MAX(case when sort = 2 then Operation end), '') operation
,   ISNULL(MAX(case when sort = 3 then Operation end), '') operation
,   ISNULL(MAX(case when sort = 4 then Operation end), '') operation
from (
    select jobnum, row_number() over(partition by jobNum order by case operation when 'Fabrication' then 0 when 'Welding' then 1 when 'paint' then 2 when 'packaging' then 3 else 4 end)AS sort
    ,   Operation + ' (' + CAST(hours as varchar(10)) + '/' + CAST(estimate as varchar(10)) + ')' AS Operation
    from (
        VALUES  (1, N'Fabrication', 5, 6, 1)
        ,   (1, N'Paint', 1, 1, 1)
        ,   (1, N'Packaging', 0, 1, 0)
        ,   (2, N'Fabrication', 6, 6, 0)
        ,   (2, N'Welding', 2, 4, 0)
        ,   (2, N'Paint', 0, 2, 0)
        ,   (2, N'Packaging', 0, 1, 0)
        ,   (3, N'Fabrication', 3, 2, 1)
        ,   (3, N'Packaging', 0.25, 0.5, 1)
    ) t (JobNum,Operation,Hours,Estimate,Completed)
    )x
group by JobNum
```

The key here is to realize the sort which puts the columns into correct slot of your table, this way every operation can be easily flipped by using MAX(CASE WHEN...) construct which is pretty much what pivot uses.

This will need some work if you have dynamic and unlimited number of operations, I'll leave it as exercise for the reader

Comment: Nice answer. I'll offer one suggestion: A `cross apply ( select Operation + ' (' + CAST(hours as varchar(10)) + '/' + CAST(estimate as varchar(10)) end + ')') AS OperationSummary ) S` can be used to eliminate the need for duplicate expressions.

Comment: Good call @TN , changed it a bit